# MASSIVE: Is there a way to use macro so you can control OSC pitch and Rate of Dimension Expander/Reverb?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects, synthesizer, synthesis, reverb

Is there a way to use macro so you can control OSC pitch and Rate of Dimension Expander/Reverb with the same macro button ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this video:

Although the person in the video doesn't set the same parameters that you would like to control with a macro, the process is still the same. Click on the upper-right corner of the macro knob you would like to have control OSC pitch and then click on the box that is linked with said parameter. After this, do the same for rate of dimension expander/reverb.